# How to update cuurent view in prism region

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I wish to know that is there a way to update my current view after loading in prism region.
My view is updated automatically  when loaded and i use lifetime interface to load every time when called. 
is there a way where we can update the current view like update folder??

Comment: not sure what you mean by "update folder", but you can use `INavigationAware` to get notified when navigated to and from

Comment: I wish reload module after an event that is received in same module

Comment: A module cannot be reloaded, it's loaded once and then it's there. Do you mean you want to reload the _view_?

Comment: Yes, i wish to reload the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the view model (and with it the view) should update itself automatically when the model changes, either through `INotifyPropertyChanged`, dedicated events, usage of the `EventAggregator` or any other message passing system.

That being said, if you want the view model to update only at a certain point in time (e.g. when the user clicks an update button), you should move the update code out of the `NavigatedTo` method and call that method from `NavigatedTo` and the `UpdateCommand`.

```
internal class MyViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    public MyViewModel( IDataSource theSourceOfData )
    {
        _theSourceOfData = theSourceOfData;
        UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand( UpdateData );
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _myProperty, value );
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; }

    #region INavigationAware
    public void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationContext navigationContext )
    {
        UpdateData();
    }
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly IDataSource _theSourceOfData;

    private string _myProperty;

    private void UpdateData()
    {
        _myProperty = _theSourceOfData.FetchTheData();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, if we click the update button, `MyViewModel.MyProperty` is updated and the change notification pushed out to the view. Same happens if we navigate to the view model.

Comment: As i have already implemented this using delegate commands, I was updating properties by calling a method that is registered in delegate command. I was curious to know about a simpler way rather than calling a method to update all the properties back. Is using DataSource fetch us in different way?

Comment: You can drop the backing field and directly access the data source in the getter of `MyProperty`, thus removing the responsibility to correctly cache data from the view model. The view model should observe the data source's `PropertyChanged` event to fire his own when a the data source changes so that `MyProperty` changes. This can be done easily and in a refactoring-safe way by using the propery observer: https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/